# ScrollTop does not work

Tags: jquery

When the page loads, I am trying to scroll header 3 upwards. Basically Header 3 should be displayed at the top most position on the page.

I am using this:

```
$(function(){
 $('body').animate({
     scrollTop: $(":header3").offset().top
}, 500);
});
```

Similarly if I use Header 4, the scroller should come down and Header 4 should be displayed at the top most position on the page.

However the scroll does not happen. Not sure why?

here's a fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/xdaf7o3b/

Comment: Are you sure jquery supports selectors like this `:header3`?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/header-selector/

Comment: Right, but wtf is `:header*3*`?

Comment: that's ok. I thought we could use a numeric after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to scroll to the third header of any sort (h1, h2, h3, h4, etc) on the page, try the :eq selector:

```
$(function(){
 $('body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(":header:eq(2)").offset().top
}, 500);
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/xdaf7o3b/5/

And to ensure there is enough space in the document to correctly scroll the viewport right to the header you want, you can do some measurement and add padding to the containing div, if required:

```
var wh = $(window).height();
var dh = $(document).height();
var top = $(":header:eq(2)").offset().top
if ((dh - top) < wh) {
    $("#someDiv").css("padding-bottom", (wh - (dh - top)) + "px")
}
```

demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/xdaf7o3b/6/

A good test for this is to try it on the 4th header of the page, demoed here: http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/xdaf7o3b/7/

Comment: this will not work as there is only one `h3` in the HTML

Comment: The question is about getting the third header on the page, regardless of whether it is an h1, h2, or h3. I wanted to show an example of the nth-child in use, but you're right that by doing this with h3 it isn't clear what I am trying to do! I will update to use :header

Comment: ahh and nth-child is wrong anyway, as there are other elements at the same level as the headers, which are counted by the nth-child selector. .eq is the one!

Comment: ...thanks, getting there! And, finally, to ensure there is enough space at the bottom of the doc to scroll accurately to the desired header, you can do some measurements - another edited coming up...

Answer (score 0):

Replace of :header3 use h3

```
$(function(){
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("h3").offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

Updated [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xh988qj5/)

Answer (score 0):

Use html body selector

```
$(function(){
 $('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $("h3").offset().top
   }, 800);
});
```

here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xdaf7o3b/2/)

Answer (score 0):

**Use below Code**

```
$(function(){
 $('body').animate({
     scrollTop: $("h3").offset().top
}, 800);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no such selector as `:header3`. You can use `:header:eq(2)` instead. Or simply `h3`.

```
$(function(){
 $('body,html').animate({
     scrollTop: $(":header:eq(2)").offset().top
}, 800);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xdaf7o3b/1/).

Comment: I think you meant eq(2). Anyways if you see your demo, your code scrolls to h4 but h4 is not the top most element. There are some lines of h3 also visible. How to make h4 scroll to the top most position?

Comment: Yep sure `eq(2)`. You can't scroll futher if you hit the bottom of the page.

Comment: yeah that doesn't help my case. Anybody else who can think of any generic solution?

Comment: I've fed Yury's :eq approach into my answer above, and added some measurement code that inserts padding to ensure the fourth header can be put at the top. This is actually a really useful technique, I can see myself using it - it is annoying when eg hash links to page headers don't quite 'work' because the header isn't right at the top because of space issues. 4th header demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/xdaf7o3b/7/

Comment: @sifriday Thanks for coming up with this excellent idea. I have marked yours as the right answer.